# Not Supported Exception on constructor of DataVisualization.Charting creating new LinearAxis

Tags: wpf, datavisualization.toolkit

I've just compiled an old project that uses Presentation Framework's DataVisualization and I'm getting a "Not Suported Exception":

> Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Property' to object of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'.
>
> at
>
> System.Windows.Markup.DependencyPropertyConverter.ResolveProperty(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String targetName, Object source)"

Great, easy to solve, just don't set a non dependency property in a setter right?

Except it's occurring on the code-behind line:

```
var la = new LinearAxis();
```

and the exception in the presentation framework itself, which I have no control over. Has anyone encountered this? How can I solve an error in an external library like this? I can't imagine it's a bug in the constructor, I must be doing something on my end that's causing it.

This is the chart style, I'll try removing it and see if that's affecting things:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:Chart}">
    <!--<Setter Property="LegendStyle" Value="{StaticResource LedgendStyle}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:Chart}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Primitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                            <Grid Panel.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" Background="{StaticResource GraphBackground}" />
                            <Border Panel.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource GraphBorder}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource GrephBorderThickness}" />
                        </Primitives:EdgePanel>
                        <visualizationToolkit:Legend 
                                    x:Name="Legend"
                                    Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="50,10"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Background="{StaticResource LegendBackground}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

One thing I've noticed, if I run without debug everything seems fine...

Comment: What library are you using? Charting Toolkit? Telerik?

Comment: Sorry thought it was "PresentationFramework", the standard .NET DataVisualization System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: Did you declare a style for the LinearAxis object? Considering just that line of code (i.e. `var la = new LinearAxis();`) your issue seems to be not reproducible

Comment: It's awfully unreproducible. Sorry! There's no style for LinearAxis defined in the project. I'll see if I can find the default one and manually add it. There is a style for the chart itself.

Comment: Trying to reproduce the bug now, and it's stopped happening altogether :|

Comment: So now it is solved ;-) Well done!